# Laravel implement mutator with save

Tags: php, laravel, model

I'm writing a Product model and I want to be able to update the product's price via the Product model. Since product's price changes and we need to keep the price history, price is in its own table and has its own model. I can find the current price of a product by pulling the most recent effective dated row from the database.

[image: product_price]

So a Product can have many prices, but a price can only have one product.

I'm exposing the "price" of the product as "unit_price" from my Product model. Showing/getting the price is easy. The `getUnitPriceAttribute()` method pull's the most recent price row based on my Product's id then returns the row's price. So I can do things like

```
$some_var = $product_instance->unit_price;
echo $some_var;
```

and the model works the way you would expect it to.

I don't know the correct way to write the `setUnitPriceAttribute()` method. With my current implementation, if I write something like

```
$product_instance->unit_price = 123;
```

then the code will add a new row to the prices table with the value 123.

If during a single web request these lines get executed,

```
$product_instance->unit_price = 1;
$product_instance->unit_price = 2;
$product_instance->unit_price = 3;
```

then the code will add 3 new rows to the prices table. All of these rows get inserted before I run the save method for the Product instance.

What's the correct way to write the `setUnitPriceAttribute()` mutator so that:

1. The rows aren't inserted into the database until the someone runs the save method for the Product.
2. Only 1 row is inserted into the database even if the Product's price is changed multiple times in a single request.
3. After you update the Product's price, you should be able to fetch the new price with the `getUnitPriceAttribute()` method.

Or should I not be using mutators and accessors for this?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'unit_price'];

    protected $appends = ['unit_price', 'available_stock'];
    protected $with = ['prices', 'warehouse_product'];

    protected $hidden = ['prices', 'warehouse_product'];


    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Price');
    }

    public function setUnitPriceAttribute($new_price)
    {
        $this->prices()->create({
            'price' => $new_price
        });
    }

    public function getUnitPriceAttribute()
    {
        $price = $this->prices()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(1)->get();
        return $price[0]->price;
    }
```

Comment: In that request, are you invoking `setUnitPriceAttribute` after latest action of `getUnitPriceAttribute` method? Side note: `$price = $this->prices()->latest()->first();`

Comment: @Tpojka Yes, I am calling setUnitPriceAtrribute after getUnitPriceAttribute.

Comment: If business logic allows it, solution 2 seems ok. After all calculations, before response insert value. Can't tell much more not knowing other application's parameters but this is how I see it.

Answer (score 0):

yes because your mutator execute at the same time when you assign the value. better if you get a instance of that save and use that instance to create that price. for eg:

```
$product = new Product
... assign your field to save in this instance

$product->save();

$product->insert([
   ['price' => 1],
   ['price' => 2],
   ['price' => 3]
]);
```